# Vb.Net Caching Sharepoint Data?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I have a simple VB.NET application that is reading and updating a SharePoint list running on Office365. This application is running on an adjustable timer. I have noticed that even though I kill all of the adodb connection and recordset variables that it is somehow caching some of the data. Consequently, the program is sometimes operating from old data and I cannot figure out how to force a connection to the live data. How do I force the application to retrieve the live data directly from Sharepoint?

I am killing all of the connection and recordset variables at the end of the timer sequence. I have stepped through the code to verify these commands are being reached. The only way I can guarantee that i am getting the live data is to stop the application and start it again. I even tried setting the object variables to nothing.

```
WriteLog("Function SyncSharePoint: Closing Objects.")
Try
    rsSharePointTasks.Close()
    rsSharePointTasks = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    SetErrorDetail("Error closing rsSharePointTasks. Exception: " & ex.Message, False)
    Return False
End Try

Try
    rsLocalTasks.Close()
    rsLocalTasks = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    SetErrorDetail("Error closing rsLocalTasks. Exception: " & ex.Message, False)
    Return False

End Try

Try
    rsUI.Close()
    rsUI = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    SetErrorDetail("Error closing rsUI. Exception: " & ex.Message, False)
    Return False

End Try

Try
    conSP.Close()
    conSP = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    SetErrorDetail("Error closing conSP. Exception: " & ex.Message, False)
    Return False

End Try

Try
    conLT.Close()
    conLT = Nothing

Catch ex As Exception
    SetErrorDetail("Error closing conLT. Exception: " & ex.Message, False)
    Return False

End Try
```

Comment: Ok - just an update. It looks like I was able to cheat and prevent the "caching" by moving the sync to a form. The timer functions call the form which performs the sync and is then closed and disposed after the sync is finished. Previously, the sync function was inside a module. I am guessing that there is a disposal method that I am unaware of that I should have been using on the object variables? Anyway, it looks like the problem is solved for now.